# How to use "menu strip" type of selection items?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

What im trying to find out, its how to use the  "menu strip" type of selection items but not using strip menu( becouse i want the same selection in the middle of the form)?i dont need menu strip, i just need to make this type of selection like: mouse point on "CAR" then CAR MODELS shows up then mouse point on "AUDI" then audi MODELS show up etc..: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXTK4.jpg   how it has to look but not on menu strip, in picture its menu strip.    What should i use to do this? thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "should be not be as menu"? The menu strip **is** a menu.

Comment: i dont need menu strip, i just need to make this type of selection  like: mouse point on "CAR" then CAR MODELS shows up  then mouse point on "AUDI" then audi MODELS show up  etc...

Comment: I don't understand - *because that's exactly what a menu-strip is*. Do you perhaps mean a "context menu"?

Comment: i dont need menu, i want to make something like this in my form for choose items

Comment: with menu it was just example want i want but dont know how to do it not ono menu

Comment: Are you looking for a [**`ComboBox`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, this question makes no sense as currently worded. Can you include another picture showing a mockup of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a MenuStrip and then change the Dock property to None.  Then you'll be able to put it anywhere on the form.

You may also want to paint the control to make it look more like a button.  Here is a simple function you add to your form's class to paint a border around your ToolStripMenuItem.

```
   Private Sub TestToolStripMenuItem_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles yourTestToolStripMenuItem.Paint
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it exactly what i was looking for, im tired of the guys who minus my qeustions , omg